# DICOM Orthanc. Text Value Attribute(0040,A160)

Tags: c++

Имеется orthanc-server и проект на C++ с использованием Grassroots DICOM. На сервере имеется запись instance c **Text Value Attribute(0040,A160)**.
Текст в формате base64 размером 1 мбайт. Создание Instance нормально производится и отправляется на сервер (gdcm::CompositeNetworkFunctions::CStore). При скачивании напрямую с сервера dicom-файла Text Value имеется. Но при запросе из моего проекта

```
std::unique_ptr<gdcm::BaseRootQuery> query(gdcm::CompositeNetworkFunctions::ConstructQuery(gdcm::ERootType::eStudyRootType, gdcm::EQueryLevel::eStudy, queryds));
std::vector<gdcm::DataSet> dataSetVector;
bool isFinded = gdcm::CompositeNetworkFunctions::CFind(m_remote.c_str(), m_port, query.get(), dataSetVector, "GDCMSCU", "ANY-SCP");
```

данные с тегом Text Value Attribute(0040,A160) не приходят.

Это как то связано с размером текста. Если отправлять небольшую строку, то все работает. Это и странно, ведь тип поля Text Value - UT размером 2^32 - 2...

Как решить данную проблему?